# Wrong row deleted from listview android

Tags: android, mysql, listview, android-adapter, delete-row

I know there are many Stack Overflow questions resolved for my issue. I tried most of the solutions, but none succeeded for me.

I am trying to implement the listrow deletion of listview.On longclick of listrow alert will popup where there are two option delete and cancel.When delete is pressed that row will be deleted in custom adapter as well as row in mysql table using async task. But only the last row gets deleted.

I have set `notifyDataSetChanged()` to my adapter. Even then it is not working fine.

This is my code:

```
     listView.setOnItemLongClickListener(new OnItemLongClickListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1,
                int position, long arg3) {
            System.out.println("postition value::" + position);
            removeItemFromList(position);

            return true;
        }
    });


    protected void removeItemFromList(int position) {
    final int deletePosition = position;
    System.out.println("deleting postition::"+deletePosition);
    AlertDialog.Builder alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());

    alert.setTitle("Delete");
    alert.setMessage("Do you want delete this item?");
    alert.setPositiveButton("YES", new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            // TOD O Auto-generated method stub

            // main code on after clicking yes
            new removefromfav().execute();
            courselist.remove(deletePosition);
        //  dataAdapter.remove(dataAdapter.getItem(deletePosition));
            dataAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            listView.setAdapter(dataAdapter);
        //  dataAdapter.notifyDataSetInvalidated();

        }
    });
    alert.setNegativeButton("CANCEL", new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            dialog.dismiss();
        }
    });

    alert.show();

}
```

My Adapter Class,

```
   private class MyCustomAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Course> {

    private ArrayList<Course> countryList;

    public MyCustomAdapter(Context context, int textViewResourceId,
            ArrayList<Course> countryList) {
        super(context, textViewResourceId, countryList);
        this.countryList = new ArrayList<Course>();
        this.countryList.addAll(countryList);
    }

    private class ViewHolder {
        TextView code;
        TextView name;
        ImageView cover;
        TextView cost;
        ImageView ratingshow;
        ImageView promoimage;
        TextView enroll;
    }

    public void add(Course country) {

        this.countryList.add(country);
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        ViewHolder holder = null;

        if (convertView == null) {

            LayoutInflater vi = (LayoutInflater) getActivity()
                    .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            convertView = vi.inflate(R.layout.course_overview, null);

            holder = new ViewHolder();
            holder.code = (TextView) convertView
                    .findViewById(R.id.coursename);
            holder.name = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.author);
            holder.cost = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.cost);
            holder.cover = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.cover);
            holder.ratingshow = (ImageView) convertView
                    .findViewById(R.id.ratingimage);
            holder.promoimage = (ImageView) convertView
                    .findViewById(R.id.promoimage);
            holder.enroll = (TextView) convertView
                    .findViewById(R.id.enroll);
            convertView.setTag(holder);

        } else {
            holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }

        Course country = this.countryList.get(position);
        holder.code.setText(country.getCode());
        holder.name.setText(country.getName());
        holder.cost.setText("$ " + country.getRegion());
        holder.cover.setImageBitmap(country.getBitmap());




        return convertView;

    }

}
```

Anyone can help me???

Comment: Did you add any footerview or headerview to your listview?

Comment: yes I have added footerview

Comment: what is this new removefromfav().execute(); ?

Comment: It is aynctask used to delete row in mysql table

Comment: Will you able to post your custom adapter file

Comment: because it may help us to find the solution

Comment: which one is getting deleted..?

Comment: last row of the list view

Comment: @NaveenKumar I have edited my question with my adapter class

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok sure i can help you you will add one more function on your custom adapter

```
   public void removeElementAtPosition(int position){
      this.countryList.remove(position);
      notifyDataSetChanged();
   }
```

and delete your adapter item in your long click function like

```
  dataAdapter.removeElementAtPosition(position);
```

you don't want to update our adapter once again. And you will check and avoid the null pointer exception

All the adapters will work with this function

```
 public int getCount(){
     this.countryList.size();         
 }
```

so, you will affect the list in this adapter your list item will decreased if you check with this getcount function **BASE ADAPTER**

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/BaseAdapter.html

All the best..

Answer (score 1):

You are not deleting anything from your `countryList` in `MyCustomAdapter`.
I see a function where you add stuff, but I don't see one removing stuff.

Add a function to remove items from your `countryList`:

```
private class MyCustomAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Course> {

private ArrayList<Course> countryList;

public MyCustomAdapter(Context context, int textViewResourceId,
        ArrayList<Course> countryList) {
    super(context, textViewResourceId, countryList);
    this.countryList = new ArrayList<Course>();
    this.countryList.addAll(countryList);
}

private class ViewHolder {
    TextView code;
    TextView name;
    ImageView cover;
    TextView cost;
    ImageView ratingshow;
    ImageView promoimage;
    TextView enroll;
}

public void add(Course country) {

    this.countryList.add(country);
}

//ADD THIS FUNCTION
public void remove(int index) {
    this.countryList.remove(index)
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    ViewHolder holder = null;

    if (convertView == null) {

        LayoutInflater vi = (LayoutInflater) getActivity()
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        convertView = vi.inflate(R.layout.course_overview, null);

        holder = new ViewHolder();
        holder.code = (TextView) convertView
                .findViewById(R.id.coursename);
        holder.name = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.author);
        holder.cost = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.cost);
        holder.cover = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.cover);
        holder.ratingshow = (ImageView) convertView
                .findViewById(R.id.ratingimage);
        holder.promoimage = (ImageView) convertView
                .findViewById(R.id.promoimage);
        holder.enroll = (TextView) convertView
                .findViewById(R.id.enroll);
        convertView.setTag(holder);

    } else {
        holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
    }

    Course country = this.countryList.get(position);
    holder.code.setText(country.getCode());
    holder.name.setText(country.getName());
    holder.cost.setText("$ " + country.getRegion());
    holder.cover.setImageBitmap(country.getBitmap());




    return convertView;

}
}
```

And call this in the `onClick` callback of your dialog

```
public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
        // TOD O Auto-generated method stub

        // main code on after clicking yes
        new removefromfav().execute();
        dataAdapter.remove(which);
        dataAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

    }
```

Comment: You're welcome. Consider upvoting my answer if it was helpfull to you